# hoy may I become {} in a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this, but I need to get this `steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]])` should return `[1, {}, 3, 4]`. But I am getting `{}` in my array

```
let b = [];
let a = JSON.stringify(arr)
let replacedArr = (a.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, ''))

for (let i = 0; i <= replacedArr.length; i++) {

    if (replacedArr[i] == 1 || replacedArr[i] == 2 || replacedArr[i] == 3 || replacedArr[i] == 4) {
        b.push(replacedArr[i] * 1)
    } else if (replacedArr[i] == "a" || replacedArr[i] == "b") {
        b.push(replacedArr[i])
    } else if (replacedArr[i] == "{") {
        b.push(replacedArr[i] + "}")
    }

}

console.log(b)
return b

}

steamrollArray([1, {},
    [3, [
        [4]
    ]]
]);
```

Comment: `==1` is a truthiness comparison, which would also be truthy for Objects. Use `=== 1` for exact comparison.

Comment: @StackSlave That's not the issue, the left hand side is a character from a string.

Comment: Do you really need to operate on the JSON string using regex and character searching?  Can't you just unwrap the array beforehand using a mapping then reduce or recursion?

Comment: @StackSlave `1 != {}`, `"1" == 1`, `1 !== '1'` -  I don't understand what you mean about it 'being thruthy for Objects'? If you just want to know that the value is `1` but not care about whether its a string of a number, `==` is just fine. And in no way does it make it difference to `objects`, either they are the same or they are not, so that comment confuses me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close to being done after `JSON.stringify()`. It might not be the best, but we can at least make this method somewhat workable. It will only work with top-level arrays, and it will obliterate any lower level arrays.

So to fix your code, let's solve the problem of trying to parse the values. Lets instead think of how we can take the string generated, and make it valid JSON again and just send it through `JSON.parse()`.

We just need to add an opening `[` to the front and a closing `]` to the end. We can do this with a template literal. Next we just Parse it. Thankfully with API-chaining we can get rid of the intermediate steps and just do it in a single line of code.

```js
const steamrollArray = (arr) => JSON.parse(`[${JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '')}]`)

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {},
    [3, [
        [4]
    ]]
]));
```

Now... this will break if we have an array inside of an Object key. We could fix that with a different regular expression to ignore any `[` or `]` inside of a matching pair of `{}`, but I'll leave that to you if you want to take it that way.

Now that we have this code, let's look at some other ways we could solve the same problems.

## Reduction and Recursion

Arrays are iterable, and thus can be traversed. They can even have cool helper methods on them! Let's use `Array.concat()` and `Array.reduce()`. But what happens if we run into another `Array`? Well let's recurse and use the function on it!

```js
const steamrollArray = (arr) => arr.reduce((newArr, value) => newArr.concat(Array.isArray(value) ? steamrollArray(value) : value), [])

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {},
    [3, [
        [4]
    ]]
]));
```

There's a lot going on here all condensed into one, but if you look through it you'll see I'm just using the built-in `Array` methods. You can find out more about these methods on [MDN for Arrays in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

## New ways to do it

Recently however we've seen even newer ways to just do this for us. For this specific use case, it's known as flattening and in most instances would be `flatten()` however due to some historical support for older website building tools, it was implemented as `flat()`. You can see it in [another answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62034428/5377773) and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Comment: Does not pass this test [1, [], [3, [[4]]]] should return [1, 3, 4] when you use JSON,CAn you help me with that. Thanks for everything!

Comment: it's because the regex will eventually leave an empty comma there. You need it to have a 0 or 1 instance of comma right after the right bracket(`]`) in the regex. you can test it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I merely used the regex you provided. Is there a reason you need to use JSON?

Comment: I do not have any reason. That is what it thought I could use to get the excercise done. https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/intermediate-algorithm-scripting-steamroller/392430/13

Comment: I would suggest avoiding it then. I pointed out that I will have problems, I can edit to expand on that. But primarily it can be buggy. Here you should use recursion. Look at the second one I provided and try to compare the two to see why you wouldn't want to use regex.

Comment: Yes, I noted this, but I do not know how to use recursion in this case.

Comment: Recursion basically means a function calls itself yo finalized a loop like condition. For this one the loop like condition is processing nested arrays. Instead of another loop, you just call the function inside itself with the new value. Think of it like taking things out if a box. If you take a box out of a box, well you have to take things out of that box too until you are done. They recur, or essentially happen again without explicitly being done. I call steamroll array if the contained value I'm concatinating is an array while executing steamrollArray.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I will work on it. I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very backward compatible, but you could use `Array.flat`:

```js
console.log([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]].flat(3));
```

Comment: this is the new-fangled way to do it and I love it. I do hate MooTools though

Comment: without using flat :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursion to solve this problem

```
let newArr = [];
const steamrollArray = (arr) => {
  for (let x of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(x)) {
      steamrollArray(x);
    } else {
      newArr.push(x);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: you should use `Array#isArray()` instead of checking the constructor name

Comment: also... those steamrolled arrays... are just vented into the ether. Shouldn't you push those too?

Comment: could you explain what do you mean by "vented into the ether"?

Comment: they get steamrolled, and then nothing is done with them. That branch essentially says "if they are an array, operate on them, then delete them."

Comment: oh... wait you have it outside the function. That's... weird

Comment: so it'll always push, but if I call it multiple times it will only push it into that same array, no matter how many different times I call it with other arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by not operating on them? I am using recursion to loop over them and it works fine

Comment: Ignore that comment. I had missed you have a single closure to the array outside of the scope of the function. I thought the `newArr` was in the function.

Comment: How are you making this work? I am using this and it is not working? where can I learn how to recursion?